# Need to use 2 @return in Sass function

Tags: css, sass

I've got this really simple Sass function:

```
@function to-rem($pxval) {
    @return #{$pxval / $base-font-size}rem;
}
```

Which converts `$pxval` to a `rem` value e.g.

```
margin-top: to-rem(24);
```

Outputs:

```
margin-top: 1.5rem;
```

IE 8 (old IE) and below don't support `rem` so to handle situations like this I have a flag for old IE which when true outputs styles to an old IE only style sheet, so for this function I was doing this and all was fine:

```
@function to-rem($pxval) {
    @if $old-ie {
        @return #{$pxval}px;
    } @else {
        @return #{$pxval / $base-font-size}rem;
    }
}
```

**BUT** because I do responsive sites I need to support Opera Mini which also doesn't support `rem` and I have no such way of filtering for Opera Mini like I do for old IE.

Any ideas how I can do this without using a mixin? I have a mixin that does the exact same thing but I use that for declaring multiple values and can handle multiple properties e.g.

```
@include to-rem(box-shadow, (inset 0 0 0 1 #2a9022) (inset 0 0 3 #459966));
@include to-rem(width height, 125);
```

I like the function for single values as it's just easier to write e.g.

```
padding: to-rem($spacing-base) 0;
```

compared to this:

```
@include to-rem(padding, $spacing-base 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer:  use a mixin.  The only way to return 2 values in any language is to return a list (or array).

```
@function to-rem($pxval) {
    @return $pxval * 1px,  $pxval / $base-font-size * 1rem;
}

.test {
    $sizes: to-rem(24);
    margin: nth($sizes, 1);
    margin: nth($sizes, 2);
}
```

The mixin clearly wins here.

Comment: Just checking, just a bit more verbose using the mixin.

Comment: Another good thing about the function is that I can use it within mixins: `@include prefix(column-gap, to-rem($spacing-base), (-webkit-, -moz-, ""));`, ah well Opera Mini will just have to miss out on these rare instances.